# How do I redirect to different php files depending on what button is pressed in the base php file?

Tags: php

I have a base php file that displays items in a database on an html table. Each row has a remove button. When pressed, it will remove that one item from the database. At the end of the table, there is an add button that once it is pressed will take you to another php file with a form that you can fill out with information to add to the database. I am having two problems. The first is that I am not sure how to determine what remove button is pushed. My second question is how do I move to a different page for the other php file once the add button is clicked? I am not supposed to use AJAX for this. And though I tried using include and isset, I couldn't get them to work properly. Any help, conceptual or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can go to other pages, simply create a form with a hidden input field holding the id of the row and have the remove button be a form submit button.

On the remove button being clicked it will go to the delete php file and redirect back to the table page.

As far as the adding button, instead of using a button just use a link to the add form.

If any of this doesn't work because of requirements you haven't mentioned let me know of any restrictions you have.

Comment: That makes sense. The only thing that contradicts is that I need to have a button for the add not a link. Everything else works, and makes sense. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Then have another form that has the add page as the action. Its a bit unorthodox but you would then just have the add button as the submit button for that form.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, just make a form for each individual row of data. that way, you will be able to pass by post the relevant id you want to remove.

Another way would be to create a "button" (not a submit button) and have the relevant onClick="..." script - like redirect to "index?Action=Remove&Id=xxxx"

By making different form for each button, you add button will have its own "action" in the form and you'll be allright!

You either have to generate a new "form" (with proper html)  if you need to pass data to your next page. If you only need to redirect depending on which button you press, you can have a onClick="..." event on your button. Make sure not to make a "submit" button :)